# Appending column from one tsv file to another (unix)

Tags: python, bash, unix

I have two tsv files, each with headers and columns. File A has headers: SampleID & RawReads, FileB has headers: SampleID & ReadsPost. I want to append ReadsPost to FileA so that the data lines up with the correct SampleID.

My original plan was to do this in python using dictionaries with the keys being sampleIDs. However, there must be an easier way to do this in bash!

Any help would be great!

Comment: Thanks! Both answers worked perfectly. I used the pandas option so I could construct a grouped bar plot with the RawReads and ReadsPost with matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join` and do a full outer join:

```
>cat test.txt test2.txt
SampleID  RawReads
1         18
2         15
5         21
7         7
SampleID     ReadsPost
1            yes
3            no
4            yes
5            yes

> join -a1 -a2 test.txt test2.txt
SampleID RawReads ReadsPost
1 18 yes
2 15
3 no
4 yes
5 21 yes
7 7
```

Note: The -a argument prints lines from the file that aren't joined. To do a full outer join, print lines from both files, as exemplified.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to load your data, you may have to set `sep='\t'` for the tab delimited sheets. Once you have your two DataFrames loaded you can use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) or [`pandas.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). For a good reference see [Merge, join, and concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) in the Pandas documentation.

Let's say your two tsv' look like this:

file1:

```
SampleID     RawReads
1            18
2            15      
5            21    
7            7
```

file2:

```
SampleID     ReadsPost
1            yes
3            no
4            yes
5            yes
```

**Using Merge**

Merge can be used to implement Database style joins on two DataFrames. In our case we can see that the two DataFrames do not agree in the SampleID column. If we want to make sure that we get all of the data from both frames we would use an `outer` join. If we only needed data from one or the other we could use a `right` or `left` join depending on what we wanted to keep. Here is an example for keeping everything.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep='\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, sep='\t')
merge_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='SampleID')
print(merge_df)
   SampleID  RawReads ReadsPost
0         1      18.0       yes
1         2      15.0       NaN
2         5      21.0       yes
3         7       7.0       NaN
4         3       NaN        no
5         4       NaN       yes
```

**Using Concat**

Concat can be used to extend DataFrames along either the row or column axis. Let's say SampleID was your index and you just wanted to concatenate the values in file2 to file1 along the column axis. For example:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep='\t', index_col='SampleID')
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, sep='\t', index_col='SampleID')
concat_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(concat_df)
          RawReads ReadsPost
SampleID
1             18.0       yes
2             15.0       NaN
3              NaN        no
4              NaN       yes
5             21.0       yes
7              7.0       NaN
```

Like I said read the Pandas documentation. It's an incredibly powerful library and a great intro to working with data in python.